# How to add two textctrl side by side in wxpython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I want to add two textctrl side by side. when i try to do that it gives me one above the other. I am trying this way

bs = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

self.t1 = wx.TextCtrl(p,size = (120,30),style = wx.TE_MULTILINE |wx.TE_CENTER)

```
    bs.Add(self.t1, 1, wx.EXPAND)

self.t2 = wx.TextCtrl(p,size = (120,30),style = wx.TE_MULTILINE |wx.TE_CENTER)
```

bs.Add(self.t2, 1, wx.EXPAND)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `wx.HORIZONTAL` box sizer

```
import wx

class Myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        bs = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.t1 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,size = (120,30),style = wx.TE_MULTILINE |wx.TE_CENTER)
        bs.Add(self.t1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.t2 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,size = (120,30),style = wx.TE_MULTILINE |wx.TE_CENTER)
        bs.Add(self.t2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(bs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = wx.App()
    Myframe().Show()
    App.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Just for once, try accepting an answer or selecting the `Useful` option, rather than saying "Thanks"